# Why can't I dereference a pointer to an object that's an array-element using the indirection operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, dereference, operator-precedence

Is it not possible to dereference a pointer to an object that's stored in an array using the indirection(dereference) operator or am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        virtual void test() {
            std::cout << "A\n";
        }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        void test() {
            std::cout << "B\n";
        }
};


int main() {
    A* v[2];

    v[0] = new A();
    v[1] = new B();

    v[0]->test();
    *(v[1]).test(); // Error! If the arrow operator is used instead
                    // though, the code compiles without a problem.

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:26:13: error: request for member ‘test’ in ‘v[1]’, which is of
pointer type ‘A*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
    *(v[1]).test();
```

Comment: is this work ? *v[1].test()

Comment: try: `(*v[1]).test()` - its the array element you want to dereference, not the return value of `test()`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator.`(member access operator) has higher precedence than `operator*`(indirection/dereference operator) , so `*(v[1]).test();` is equivalent to `*((v[1]).test());`, which is not valid. (You can't call `test()` on `v[1]` which is `A*` via `opeartor.`.)

Change it to

```
(*v[1]).test();
```

Comment: Or use the arrow operator as the compiler so helpfully suggests.

Comment: @Kevin Well, OP has used it in `v[0]->test();`, I think he just wants to know how to use the indirection operator to accomplish it.

Answer (score 17):

The proper way is this:

```
(*v[1]).test();
```

Here you first index the array and get the pointer (`v[1]`), then you dereference the pointer (`*v[1]`) and finally call the method by object value.

In your example you first tried to call `test` using `.` on `v[1]`, which is a pointer. And only after that you dereferenced the method's return value, which is also nonsense as `test` returns void.